# No dialog to buy a plot in Skyrim Hearthfire appears

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So I had Skyrim before special edition and now I finally bought SE because of the DLC's and I transferred my old account (level 43) to SE. I have all the houses (I think all not 100% sure, and had them before SE) and I have 2 children so the mod is working. But still whenever I talk to the Jarls no new dialog appears just the old chatter, I've tried a lot of things that people have suggested on other threads but none have yet worked. Can someone help me I think I gave all the information needed (I hope)

Comment: Is there any hold/property in particular that you'd like help with or were you hoping someone would solve all three at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

The Hearthfire DLC that's attached in the Special Edition doesn't add dialog to the Jarls to purchase land until you receive a letter from the Jarl of Falkreath. The letter states that he is interested in selling land and it gives you a miscellaneous quest to go and speak to the Jarl in Falkreath. The Jarl will have quests for you to complete before you can purchase land.

Also just so you know, you have to do the Waking Nightmare daedric quest to buy from Dawnstar, and the Laid to Rest side quest to buy from Morthal. Being Thane I believe is also a requirement.

This could also be a glitch if you haven't received a letter yet.